# Convert OS X .pages file to PDF or HTML preserving hyperlinks

Tags: macos, conversion, iwork-pages

Just wondering if anyone knows how to convert a Pages file to a PDF or HTML file while preserving the hyperlinks within the document.

I can export it to .PDF (using OS X Lion 10.7.3) but and the links are blue and underlined but they aren't links anymore.

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem and could not. When I export to PDF from Pages, my hotlinks still work. Have you got the latest updates?

Comment: I second that. I'm running 10.7.3 and Pages version 4.1 (923), and hyperlinks work perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

I thought Pages was something that came with the OS but I realised that the .pages files were actually opening in Preview. So I purchased Pages from the app store and voila I can export them.

I needed to create HTML files from them, I found an article that suggested exporting them to .rtf and then from the terminal running

```
textutil -convert html myfile.rtf
```

It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

With Pages 5, you can export to .epub, change them to .zip, and then unzip it to get find an .xhtml file inside.